# Filter out all rows in a dataframe containing '**'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I am trying to filter out all rows in a DataFrame that contain the substring `'**'`.

I have tried doing this with

```
df = df[~df['title'].str.contains('**')]
```

However I keep getting an error

> error: nothing to repeat at position 0

and can't figure out why.

Comment: Perhaps the error _message_ might give you, or us, a clue?

Comment: Yeah, error messages usually tell you exactly what's wrong, so we usually don't ignore them.

Comment: Do all your dataframe's rows has a 'column' named _title_? Anytway: please post  the error and a portion of your dataframe that produces that error

Comment: You probably need to pass `regex=False` to `str.contains`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to escape the `*` character using `\`, as it is being read as the special regex character `*` (meaning zero or more). In your case:

```
df[~df['title'].str.contains('\*\*')]
```

**Example**:

```
>>> df
   title
0    xyz
1  x**yz
2     **
3     x*

df[~df['title'].str.contains('\*\*')]

  title
0   xyz
3    x*
```

Answer (score 3):

By default [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) uses [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search), which considers `*` to be a special character (matching 0 or more characters). You want to call with `contains('**', regex=False)` to avoid using `re.search` - and instead use the Python `in` operator.

Comment: @iceokoli No worries. If performance is a concern in your case, it is worth noting that this method (not using regex) is more than twice as fast for me on large DataFrames.